# How a non-zero mean Gaussian can be generated from shifting a zero-mean Gaussian?

Tags: normal-distribution

We have the random variables:
 $$ m \sim N(0, K_m)$$
and
$$f \sim N(m, K_f)  $$

Supposedly the $f$ Gaussian is the same as $f \sim N(0, K_m + K_f)$

What is the proof or why is it like that if it is obvious?

Comment: Perhaps you want to re-think and re-phrase your question, since  the sentence "Supposingly..." does not hold, as it stands. Perhaps you meant "Supposingly, f+m" ? (moreover, you need in addition to assume independence).

Comment: yes they are independent. Just added it to the question. Thanks for spotting it

Comment: You still need to consider the other problem I am mentioning with your question.

Comment: How can $f$ and $m$ possibly be independent when $f$ *explicitly* depends on $m$??

Comment: You have a gaussian, m which acts as the mean for another gaussian and the result is as shown. Why is that?.. Could you repeat the problem? No-one is saying anything about f+m. We are not asked to add.

Comment: But you *are* adding!  Although it might not be obvious, it ought to become obvious when you consider that $f$ can be written as $m$ plus an $N(0,K_f)$ variable (which we might call $g$, say), whence $f=m+g$. I suspect you intend to assume $m$ and $g$ are independent.

Comment: Is f the same random variable each time you reference it? Your notation is confusing. Since you say f has mean m it really does look like m and f have to be dependent random variables. If the second f has mean 0 doesn't it have to be conditioned on m=0 and if so why then wouldn't the distribution of f then have variance K_f since conditionally m is the constant 0?!

Comment: If you have confused both me and Bill Huber in different ways doesn't that tell you that your notation is bad?

Comment: No confusion, what you see is what you get. There is no first and second f. There is only one f. The first term is given the second is derived but I do not know how. m is a random variable. I guess to sample f you must first sample m.

Comment: @Michael Please speak for yourself.  I don't feel confused and I find the notation to be conventional, clear, and accurately employed (once we infer that the second parameter is a variance and not a standard deviation).  I was pointing out an inconsistency in the OP's *statements*, one that might help him identify the essential elements of the question and its resolution.

Comment: George, Francis Galton thought so much of this result that he invented a machine to illustrate it, the *Quincunx*.  Read his own description at *Natural Inheritance* (1889), pp 63, 67, and 68 (http://www.mugu.com/galton/books/natural-inheritance/pdf/galton-nat-inh-1up-clean.pdf).  The translation is this: $m$ denotes the location of an "AA compartment" and $f$ denotes the location of a "BB compartment" *relative to an AA compartment above it.*

Comment: @whuber i'm sorry for saying that you were confused.  I should try to read into your intentions with your comments. Now I ask you If the use of the f is the same in every reference, how is the f distributed N(m, K_f) the same f that is distributed N(0, K_f +K_m)? I read into this that the second f here is really f conditioned on m=0.  That would explain why the mean is 0 in the second case.  But then since we condition on m the variance of this f should still be K_f as under the conditioning m is constant.

Comment: @Michael Those two $f$'s are the same in the sense Francis Galton was describing: the first $f$ refers to the final positions of beads as they fall through the bottom portion of the Quincunx while the second $f$ refers to to final positions of beads as they fall through the entire Quincunx.  Thus they amount to two equivalent descriptions of the same random variable.  These *descriptions* differ only in that the former description also mentions $m$, which is the position of the beads after they have fallen through the upper portion.

Comment: @whuber relating the question to a Quincunx is interesting but it wasn't suggested in the original question.  I remember when I was a child I saw a Quincunx for the first time at the Museum of Science in Chicago.  It was fascinating to see the balls fall and form the bell shaped pattern after a large number came down and it worked that way every time!  I see it as a physical demonstration of the central limit theorem. Actually it is the version for the binomial.

Comment: This is the response from our supervisor: Any vector of values f is the sum of two independent Gaussian vectors: m and a zero-mean draw from N(0, Kf). Thus any set of values are marginally drawn from f∼N(0,Km+Kf). I have to admit that this supervisor is much smarter than me to be able to communicate with him in a proper level. You see for him is obvious. If you can explain why that would be awesome